# Determining basic vector components from coordinate axes

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors

I am wondering how the components of a vector with a given angle are developed with respect to a coordinate axis. I thought that from the direction cosines of a vector, the component of a vector can be found by projecting the vector onto the coordinate axis multiplied by the angle between it.

[Direction cosines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPTmR.png)

How then are the four sections of the rotated x' and y' components found geometrically? Why is the $xsin\phi$ in respect to the x-coordinate and not y? And similarly why is the $ycos\phi$ the "cosine" and not $ysin\phi$ if it makes an angle with the vertical axis? Once I define an angle between two sections, how do I know which axis I need to compare to from the mixed dotted line with $xsin\phi$ and $ycos\phi$?

[Rotation of xy-axis about z-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWOpQ.png)